# Filling a range with array elements based on randomly generated array index

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I am creating a program that will create a random workout routine per day/body part.

Below is my code which, hopefully, creates an array of just abdominal exercises from a list of 100 exercises. Once the array is created, a random index number is chosen. I want to fill four rows of the of the abToday range with this element.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim roll
roll = Int((7 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

If roll = 1 Then
    'Gets all available ab movements
    Dim abdominals() As Variant
    abdominals = Sheets("KEY").Range("A2" & Rows.CountIf("A:A", "Abdominals")).End(xlUp).Row

    'Creates today's ab routine
    Dim abToday As Range
    Set abToday = Range("A7:A22")
    RandomSample = Int((UBound(abdominals, 1) - LBound(abdominals, 1) + 1) * Rnd + 1)

End Sub
```

Can anyone offer any direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark because it doesn't appear to follow your code, but see if something like this will work:

```
Private Sub GetAbs()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow, row, i As Integer
  Dim abToday As Range

  Set abToday = Range("A7:A22")
  Set ws = Sheets("KEY")

  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

  For i = 0 To 3
    row = Int(LastRow * Rnd + 1)
    Cells(abToday.row + i, abToday.Column).Value = ws.Cells(row, 1).Value
  Next i

End Sub
```

Bear in mind it does not do a dupe check, meaning it's conceivable that the logic will list the same exercise more than once from time to time.  To overcome that should not be a big deal, though...  but it depends on whether or not that matters.

Comment: This almost works! However, it generates an array from the entire list of exercises, rather than just locating the ab movements then randomly pulling 4 ab movements from that. I'll mess around with what you posted. it's halfway there thanks Hambone! You are a both a gentleman and scholar.

Comment: Aah, I see.  I did not catch that.  If you run into a roadblock, send a sample of what your "exercises" spreadsheet looks like.  If the exercises are jumbled with the exercise type a Dictionary object may prove useful.